# Bilinearly interpolating overlapping image patches

Tags: python, image-processing

I am given a 576x576 pixel image, that is split up into patches of 64x64 pixels, with a step size of 32 pixels in the horizontal and vertical direction, allowing an overlap of half in both dimensions. For example, in a 128x64 pixel image, I would have 3 patches, like in the first attached image.

These 64x64 image patches are fed to a neural network model that is trained to classify the patches as either being dirty or clean, with a certain probability (evaluation score). Using the 128x64 pixel image example, after feeding the 3 patches through the model, I would for example have an

- evaluation score of 0.61 for patch (0, 0), (64, 64)
- evaluation score of 0.52 for patch (32, 0), (96, 64)
- evaluation score of 0.43 for patch (64, 0), (128, 64)

where (x1, y1), (x2, y2) denote the top-left and bottom-right coordinate of a patch, respectively.

I now want to display a heat map on top of the original image, that shows the evaluation scores of every pixel, by bilinearly interpolating between the patches, as seen in the second attached image.

The problem I have right now is that I only have an evaluation score for an entire 64x64 image patch, whereas I want a pixel evaluation score.
My assumption now is that the evaluation score of a patch corresponds to one of its central pixels, e.g. the first patch's central pixel is at (32, 32), and its value is 0.61, and the second patch's central pixel is at (64, 32) and its value is 0.52.

My question now is: how can this be turned into an interpolation problem to obtain an evaluation score for unknown pixels, such as pixel (0, 0) or pixel (48, 32), given that I only have the evaluation score for pixels (32, 32), (64, 32) and (96, 32) as respresented by the red squares in the first attached image.

[image: Overlapping patches]

[1] Overlapping patches

[image: Cleanliness heatmap]

[2] Evaluation score heatmap

Comment: So for the first 3 patches, you only have the correct values for the first half of `Patch 0` and the second half of `Patch 2`? You want to recover the first half of `Patch 1` from a sum of the actual first part (that you do not know) and the second part of `Patch 0`?

Comment: No, I have the values for the center pixels of patch 0, 1 and 2, and want to use these get the per-pixel evaluation scores to construct the heatmap you can see in my edited answer.

Comment: I think you should edit your question and explain your issue in more detail. I still have no good idea what you are trying to achieve based on your question and this comment.

Comment: I have edited my post, hopefully this clears things up. If anything is still unclear please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scipy.interpolate.griddata`. Linear interpolation mode will interpolate values in-between of your known points and will fill the values at the edges with a provided value or nan.

I am providing code for a slightly bigger example than yours since your example doesn't have any "in-between" points in the y-dimension, and the linear interpolation mode will throw an error (though the "nearest" mode will work).

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

# create a meshgrid of the coordinates you want to interpolate onto
height = 96
width = 160
y = np.arange(height)
x = np.arange(width)
x,y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

# these are your known values for known points
points = np.array([[32,32], [32, 64], [32, 96], [32, 128], [64,32], [64, 64], [64, 96], [64, 128]])
values = np.array([0.61, 0.52, 0.43, 0.39, 0.53, 0.45, 0.66, 0.20])

# convert the grid coordinates to a list
coords_list = np.asarray([[y[i, j], x[i, j]] for i in range(len(y)) for j in range(len(x[0]))])

# interpolate the known points onto the list of grid points
predicted_values = griddata(points, values, coords_list, method='linear', fill_value=0)

# reshape the predicted values to fit your image shape
predicted_values_grid = predicted_values.reshape([height, width])
```

This is how the `predicted_values_grid` will look like:

[image: interpolated image]

The values between the provided points got interpolated, while the points at the edges were filled with zeros.